# How to tell GNU screen to run .bash_profile in each new window?

Tags: gnu-screen

When I open a new window in GNU screen, it runs `.bashrc` but not `.bash_profile`. In my setup, this results in some environment variables not being set up correctly in that window.

How can I tell GNU screen to always run `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc` on opening a new window? (Please don't tell me to just call `.bash_profile` from my `.bashrc` :)

Answer (score 36):

You want to start bash (or whatever shell) as a login shell. You do this with

```
shell -$SHELL
```

in your `~/.screenrc`. The magic is the `-` before the shell. See `man screenrc` for details. (Well, not many more details, because that's pretty much it.)

Comment: When I do this it stops screen starting in the directory I use the command from. How can I make screen use the directory I launch the command from as the directory it starts up in?

Comment: I don't get that manpage!  The online docs are here though: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Shell.  I got confused initially as the screenrc is only reread when a screen gets recreated - not each time you make a new window within the application

Comment: @theonlygusti For me, the working directory is preserved when setting up .screenrc as suggested.

Comment: Is there a way to tell screen to source a SPECIFIC rc file?  I am on a shared system, and am new to a team of 35.  They are used to their very customized .bashrc && .bash_profile files, and I have a file named .mybash.rc that I can simply "source ~/mybash.rc" every single time I create a new window in screen, but I wish I didn't have to do this every time.  Is there a way to have this done from my screenrc?

Answer (score 2):

You would either need to source `~/.bash_profile` from `~/.bashrc` or put the things you need directly into `~/.bashrc` or put the things in common in a third file and source it from both your `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: WHERE to source those ? ... be cuz THAT IS THE PROBLEM (screen do NOT source any of them)

Comment: @THESorcerer: On my system, `screen` sources `~/.bashrc` without the `shell` command shown in the other answer.